# Camera view/projection issue

Tags: camera, lwjgl, opengl-es3

I made a simple OpenGL program but I can figure out why the camera is not working, here it's a little fragment of the Camera class:

```
public Matrix4f getView() { // initializes the view matrix
    return new Matrix4f().lookAt(
            new Vector3f(0f, 0f, 1f), // camera position at 0,0,1
            new Vector3f(0f, 0f, 0f), // camera target at 0,0,0
            new Vector3f(0f, 1f, 0f)); // up axis set to "worldUp" (0,1,0)
}

public Matrix4f getProjection() {
    return new Matrix4f().perspective(
            (float) Math.toRadians(fieldOfView), // the fov has a value between 0f and 180f, by default I set it to 90° 
            viewportAspectRatio, // the aspect ratio is equal to 1024 / 960 (screen height / screen width)... even if I've not understood what is it...
            0.1f, 1000f); // I've not really understood what near and far planes are...
}

public Matrix4f getMatrix() { // with this function I obtain the final camera matrix
    return getView().mul(getProjection());
}
```

And it's how I handle the camera Matrix in GLSL, created using `camera.getMatrix()`:

```
gl_Position = camera * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

Without the camera all is fine: here's the program running using `gl_Position = model * vec4(position, 1.0);`:

[image: lol]

*(Yeah, it's a cube)*

But using the camera in the way I showed you before, increasing the FOV, I get this:
[image]

Could anyone look at my code and tell me where I'm wrong? I would be really happy... D:

Comment: Are your vertices defined in clip-space?

Comment: In clip-space? I think yes, look at the cube without camera, all seems fine.

Comment: That would be -1:1 components with model set to identity?

Comment: I'm using modern opengl so i don't really know what identity is. With the VBO buffer i loaded correct vertices, i'm sure of that. With the model Matrix i Made a 'null' Matrix which has 1,1,1 of scale and 0,0,0 of translate.

Comment: Let just eliminate viewproj as a possible issue first. Please add the array of values produced by `getMatrix` to your answer and I'll compare them to my DX RH methods.

Comment: I'm not at home at the moment, i'm sorry...

Answer (score 1):

I solved, the problem was on `getMatrix`. Has *Jon* say I had to flip `getView().mul(getProjection())` to obtain `getProjection().mul(getView())`. At first I though that this would not change anything but I was wrong. Thank you *Jon*!

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative.